# Breeze query string parameters

Tags: breeze

Breeze query is sending the null string parameters as "null" to the breeze controller. The parameter should just get sent as null instead of "null". The non string parameters are sent as null which is correct.

How can I solve this problem ? My breeze query looks like below:

```
  var getFaxes = function (faxesArray,agencyName) {
        var query = EntityQuery.from('Faxes')
                    .inlineCount()
                    .withParameters({
                         agencyName: agencyName});

        function querySuceeded(data) {
            faxesArray(data.results);
        }

        return manager.executeQuery(query)
            .then(querySuceeded)

    };
```

agencyName is initialised as null. There are lot of other parameters as well but I have only included the string parameter.

The controller method looks like below:

```
public IQueryable<Fax> ReturnFaxes([FromUri]Filtermodel filterModel)
{
    //here I notice that filterModel.agencyName is received as "null" instead of null
    //Filtermodel contains a string property called AgencyName.
}
```

Comment: Sorry, need to see an example of what your EntityQuery.withParameters call looks like.

Comment: @JayTraband I have added little code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This used to occur with older versions of either breeze or jQuery ( assuming you are using the default jquery ajax adapter), but shouldn't any longer.  What version of breeze and jQuery are you using? If you are using the 'angular' http service instead it should not have this issue either.

Comment: Breeze version is 1.4 and jQuery version is 1.9.1.